# Where did I go wrong in this proof (bound not tight enough)?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence:

$a_1 = 3$

$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{1}{a_n}$

First I proved $a_n > 0$ for all $n$

I know the limit is $\sqrt{2}$ and want to show it is bounded below by it.

Here are some steps for the inductive case:

$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n^2 + 2}{2a_n} = \frac{a_n^2 - 3a_n + 2 + 3a_n}{2a_n} = \frac{1}{a_n}\frac{a_n^2 - 3a_n + 2}{2} + \frac{3}{2} > 0 \cdot {a_n}\frac{a_n^2 - 3a_n + 2}{2} + \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$

In particular, I bounded it from below with $\frac{3}{2}$ and without using the inductive hypothesis, but I know that there exists a point when it will be $< \frac{3}{2}$, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: You are saying that $c>0$ implies $cd> (0)(d)=0$. Clearly false when $c=1,d=-1$.

Comment: So the issue is $\frac{a_n^2 - 3a_n + 2}{2}$ could be negative? How would you fix the proof?

Comment: The closed-form expression of $a_n$ is

$$a_n =\sqrt{2}+ 2\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2^n}}{(\sqrt{2}+1)^{2^n}-(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2^n}}$$

Comment: Wow. How do you work to obtain that? @NN2

Comment: @user129393192 I added an answer for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

We observe that

$$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{a_n^2+2}{2a_n}-\sqrt{2} =\frac{a_n^2+2 -2\cdot a_n\cdot\sqrt{2}}{2a_n} = \frac{(a_n-\sqrt{2})^2}{2a_n} \tag{1} $$
$$a_{n+1}+\sqrt{2}=\frac{a_n^2+2}{2a_n}+\sqrt{2} =\frac{a_n^2+2 +2\cdot a_n\cdot\sqrt{2}}{2a_n} = \frac{(a_n+\sqrt{2})^2}{2a_n} \tag{2} $$
Let $(1)/(2)$, we deduce:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{n+1}+\sqrt{2}} = \left( \frac{a_{n}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{n}+\sqrt{2}} \right)^2$$
$$\implies  \frac{a_{n}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{n}+\sqrt{2}}=\left( \frac{a_{n-1}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{n-1}+\sqrt{2}} \right)^2=...=\left( \frac{a_{1}-\sqrt{2}}{a_{1}+\sqrt{2}} \right)^{2^{n-1}}=\left( \frac{3-\sqrt{2}}{3+\sqrt{2}} \right)^{2^{n-1}}=\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}+1} \right)^{2^{n}}$$

And you deduce easily the closed form formula of $a_n$. You can conclude also that $(a_n)_n$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$ by noticing that $(\sqrt{2}-1)^{2^n} \xrightarrow{n\to+\infty}0$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $(x-\sqrt 2)^{2}\ge 0$. For $x>0$ this can be re-written as $\frac  x 2+\frac 1 x \geq \sqrt 2$. Thus, $a_n \ge \sqrt 2$ for all $n>1$.

Let us show that $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$. For this we need $\frac x 2+\frac 1 x \le x$. But this  is same as $\frac  1 x \leq \frac x 2$ or $x \ge \sqrt 2$.

Since $a_n$ is decreasing and positive, it has  a limit $l$. We can find $l$ by taking limit in the given equation.

Note: We don't have to know before hand that the limit is $\sqrt 2$. This number appears naturally in our attempt to prove that  $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$.